# Are there codes that detect the position of an error?

Tags: reference-request, coding-theory

I am looking for code that detect an error and it's position (or an aproximation of it), this is more than an error detector code but a little less than a correcting code.

Do you know something like this or some literature that I can check?

Comment: If you can correct an error, then by comparing the received codeword to the corrected one, you can identify the position of the error.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks for your comment, yes what you said is true but that won't be near to optimal because I need just the location of the error and not the correction itself.

Comment: If you know the locations of the errors, you can correct them.